# MySQL Procedure Efficiency and Safety for Bulk Insertion and Updating the Same Record in a Cluster

Tags: mysql

I have a table for managing items in a warehouse with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `barcode` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `barcode_UNIQUE` (`barcode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Each item in this table is associated with an SKU (Stock Keeping Unit) and has a unique ID that serves as its primary key. Additionally, each item is required to possess a unique 13-digit barcode, which is generated by prefixing the ID with zeros to ensure it consists of exactly 13 digits.

We often need to insert a significant number of records for each item. To facilitate this, we've implemented a procedure that accepts both the SKU and the quantity of records to be inserted. Within this procedure, we perform individual record insertion, followed by updating each record's barcode with the corresponding added ID. This process is repeated (in single transaction) based on the specified number of records.

Here's the procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `bulk_insert_into_item`(IN inSku varchar(100), IN inSize INT)
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
    SET @counter = 0;
    REPEAT
        INSERT INTO item(sku) VALUES (inSku);
        SET @recordId =  LAST_INSERT_ID();
        UPDATE item SET barcode =lpad(@recordId, 13, 0)  WHERE id = @recordId;
        SET @counter = @counter + 1;
    UNTIL @counter >= inSize END REPEAT;
    COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I have concerns about the efficiency of this procedure, particularly in two key aspects:

1. How well does the procedure perform when adding a large number of
   items?
2. Will the table reading be locked at the time of inserting?
3. Our database is clustered, is the procedure safe for
   concurrent insertion of multiple items?

Any insights or suggestions on improving the efficiency and safety of this procedure would be greatly appreciated.

Get suggestions to improve the efficiency and safety of this procedure

Comment: As far as "locking": read about MySQL "isolation levels": https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html.  As far as "safety" in your clustered environment: you should be OK.

Comment: 1) test it with large amounts of data and you will see. 2) no 3) the cluster is safe, not your procedure

Comment: What is the reason to store statically the value which can be obtained from another value of the same row? Remove barcode column at all then either calculate your barcode value in the query or create and use according view. Also you may specify ZEROFILL attribute for `id` column.

Comment: @paulsm4
I meant by safe in terms of LAST_INSERT_ID() function use, will it always be according to the current added record? If the procedure is multiple times concurrently, will the value of LAST_INSERT_ID be affected? Or will every call lock the insertion?

Comment: @Shadow I've tested it, but with limit concurrent calls, need to make sure it will be ok with huge calls, regarding safety, please see my previous comment

Comment: @Akina 
The table already exists, and it initially used UPC_A barcodes generated mathematically, consisting of 12 digits. Each item was added individually. However, as the table's usage grew, the insertion process became slow. Therefore, we realized that using UPC_A barcodes in this table was unnecessary. Consequently, we transitioned to a different barcode (prefixing the ID with zeros) with 13 digits instead of 12 to prevent duplicates. Currently, we cannot remove the barcode since it plays a vital role in both business and technical operations

Comment: Then you need to test it with "huge calls". If this is an area of concern, then you have to test it and must not rely on some unknown person here on SO saying that everything is fine. Last_insert_id is connection safe.

Comment: Thanks, @Shadow! I'm testing it and the alternatives

Comment: By "cluster", do you mean "InnoDB Cluster"?  Or "Galera Cluster"?  Or something else?

Comment: When is the `barcode` set?

Comment: Why pre-insert empty rows?  Why not grab a new SKU when needed?

Comment: I'm asking these questions because `INSERTing` or `UPDATEing` one row is 10 times as inefficient as having a single `INSERT`/`UPDATE` with 100 rows -- even with the transaction around them.

Comment: @Akina - `ZEROFILL` is going away, but some combination of LPAD/CONCAT/RIGHT can achieve the same goal.  (Deprecated in 8.0.17)

Comment: The `UPDATE` can be completely eliminated by using a `GENERATED` column.

Comment: @RickJames, Regarding the cluster, it is InnoDB Cluster. Actually, our system is multi-tenant, and the barcode format is something like CONCAT(RPAD(tenantId, 3, '0'), LPAD(id, 10, '0')). As I mentioned before, there are many queries that depend on the barcode, and we just changed the format of the barcode. Some systems are integrated with our system, and they use this column. We have tested this approach (see fiddle solution), but recently, we have encountered a deadlock issue when concurrent calls are executed.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bulk_insert_into_item (IN inSku varchar(100), IN inSize INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO item (sku)
  WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT 1 id UNION ALL SELECT id + 1 FROM cte WHERE id < inSize
    )
  SELECT inSku FROM cte;
  UPDATE item SET barcode = LPAD(id, 13, '0') WHERE id >= LAST_INSERT_ID() AND sku = inSku;
END
```

or

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bulk_insert_into_item (IN inSku varchar(100), IN inSize INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO item (sku)
  WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT 1 id UNION ALL SELECT id + 1 FROM cte WHERE id < inSize
    )
  SELECT inSku FROM cte;
  UPDATE item SET barcode = LPAD(id, 13, '0') WHERE barcode IS NULL;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TBzGjpSn)

Comment: Thanks @Akina, it is working fine, but surround it with START TRANSACTION and COMMIT to rollback the changes in case any failure occurred during update for example

Comment: check this https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-stored-procedure/0596100892/re31.html

Comment: @AliAsfour *but surround it with START TRANSACTION and COMMIT* Do this if you need in. And add according exit handler.

Comment: what do you mean by exit handle?

Comment: I mean `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER ..`

Comment: "id + 1" will conflict with other servers in the Cluster.  Probably `auto_increment_increment` is set to 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only occasionally encountering a deadlock, catch it and rerun the procedure.  It should work on the second try.  You should add this code even if some process *theoretically* eliminates the deadlock.

If you are often deadlocking, then speeding up the procedure will reduce the frequency of deadlocks.  A `REPEAT` (or other loop) is terribly slow, especially with 2 SQLs inside it.  I don't know whether Akina's 'recursive CTE' will be faster, but it has the potential -- 1 big SELECT + 1 INSERT + 1 UPDATE.  3 big-ish SQLs will probably be a lot faster than the current 200.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I'm testing it with try and catch

Comment: and timeings...